# App to earn Google Play store credits

Tags: android, finance, play-store, google

There is an app in the Google Play store I would like to purchase that is not available elsewhere.  Ethics and morals guide me in my decision not to give any money to Google.  Similarly, I don't pirate software.  Can anyone recommend a legitimate app to earn a small amount of Google Play store credit so I can purchase this app?

The app you recommend can run on any platform (it doesn't have to be an Android app) and can even be a web-app.  All I ask is that it is legitimate, and not some sort of scam.  Oh, I also ask that it doesn't have any intrusive permissions.

I did try Google Opinion Rewards, but I didn't receive any opinion surveys, likely because I don't share GPS data with Google.

Comment: If you're not just focussed on Play credits, you can – as usual – check with my [corresponding list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_jobs). But note that all those apps have one thing in common: you pay your earnings with massive amounts of personal data, just see the "tracker" information attached (up to 18 for a single app). Not worth the effort, if you ask me – but YMMV.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks Izzy. Yep, all I want is a small amount of Google Play credit, or I suppose something that can be converted into it.  I'm not willing to give up real personal info, but I'm willing to fill out some surveys, watch some ads, review things, or click on a few buttons every day. I could also use a device that doesn't have any personal info, which actually, might be all my devices at this point.

Comment: Depending on where you live and what defines a "small" amount for you: there are voucher cards available in super markets, with USD15, 25 and 50. Might be the easier (and more reliable) way to achieve that goal. But well, I'm out at that point – I don't even have a Play account anymore (Google closed mine as they got no more data from it – all my devices run "Google-free").

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I could buy a card.  But then I'm giving money to Google, and I just can't bring myself to support a company that behaves like they do.  Also, I just want to earn a few euros/dollars to buy one app... no use for a big gift card.  Regarding your last sentence, I'm going to have to ping you in chat to learn the story about that! ;)

Comment: Buying a card you give them some bucks. Solving their tasks you give them something much more valuable: life time and personal data. From what I remember, you will spend an hour for a buck or so… So unless you got nothing to do anyway, I'd say it isn't worth it. // Other answers in chat :)

Comment: There is one way to get (certain) paid apps without giving money to Google: Many apps make app sales to increase popularity. Some reduce the price you have to pay and some even set the price to zero. Apps like [AppSales](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tsapps.appsales) can monitor those apps and inform you if the app you want is on sale. This only works if the author makes app sales. The only other alternative is to buy a Google gift coupon. I have seen that you can order those cards on Amazon using a custom amount.

Comment: Is asking directly the developer an option? While the "standard" way to install programs on Android is to go though Google, you may also be able to buy and download straight from him instead, thus bypassing Google entirely. Also take into account that when you buy a program on the Play Store most money goes to the developer too, while Google takes a commision on the sale only (if that makes you a little better).